# unable to correctly install parcel using npm

Tags: npm, parcel

I'm using the command 'npm -g install parcel-bundler', to install parcel globally and get no error, but then it doesn't seem to be installed.
When i run the command 'parcel --version' i get 'command not found', same for any other 'parcel' commands. I've tried running the 'install' command again and I get a 'parcel-bundler@1.12.4
updated 2 packages in 20.003s'. i have several 'deprecated' warnings, could the problem come from that ?
here they are :

> npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
> npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
> npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
> npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
> npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
> npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
> npm WARN deprecated request-promise-native@1.0.9: request-promise-native has been deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
> npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
> /Users/user.npm-packages/bin/parcel -> /Users/user/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/parcel-bundler/bin/cli.js

Thanks

EDIT : I have tried updating all the deprecated items manually and re-installing Parcel, it didin't fix the problem.

Comment: Which version of `npm` are you using? I encountered this problem today when configuring a development environment on a seldom used laptop. I realized my `npm` version was very out of date at 3.5.2. Once I upgraded to 6.14.10, I was able to install `parcel`.

Comment: I am at 6.14.6. I will update it and try it again then. Thanks for the tip !

Comment: @TylerMoore I've tried updating npm using the command 'npm install -g npm' and it seemed successfull, but when I run 'npm --version' I am still at the 6.14.6. Seems like thereis something pretty wrong going on.

Comment: I had the same problem getting the latest version first in my PATH. `which npm` was returning `/usr/bin/npm`, but the `npm install -g npm` command installs it to `/usr/local/bin/npm` without updating the symlink at `/usr/bin/npm`. I tried fixing that symlink with `ln -s /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/bin/npm`, but kept getting a circular reference error. In the end I uninstalled everything node and npm, reinstalled with apt, and upgraded it.

Still, your version is very recent. I suspect you may have a different problem entirely. Good luck. I'm new to Parcel and love it!

Answer (score 1):

Recently I encountered the same problem and while I don't fully understand why this happens, I manage to find some workarounds to run parcel:

- After installation using npm, run the same commands but adding `npx` before them, for example, I create a server through `npx parcel index.html`;
- Install it using yarn (`yarn add parcel-bundler`) and then, for example, run a server (`yarn parcel index.html`). Same deprecated warnings here but they don't prevent the package from running;

Update: if install the package locally there are even more ways.

- You can do what `npx` does under the hood: `./node_modules/.bin/parcel --version`;
- Create custom shorthand command in `package.json`. Under `scripts` object add `"server": "parcel index.html"`. The part before colon can be named anything you like. After that run `npm run server` and this would work.

Comment: i had same ploblem. this solution helpull to me. thank you!!!